# How to get the position of a returned array from a MATLAB function in one line

Tags: arrays, function, matlab

When trying to get the position of an item returned by a function in MATLAB, I always need two rows of code.

For example, I currently do this:

```
testString = 'Hello!';
strSize = size(testString); % returns two dimensions: [1,6] 
strSize = strSize(2);  % returns one dimension: 6
```

But, I'd like to do this, as possible in Javascript:

```
testString = 'Hello!';
strSize = size(testString)(2); % returns one dimension: 6
```

Is there any trick in MATLAB to get the return of the 'size' function and, in the same row, ask for a specific position in the array?

Thanks, colleagues!

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
[strSize1 strSize2] = size(testString);
```

Because you only want strSize2, you can also do

```
[~ strSize] = size(testString)
```

Comment: or `size(testString,2)`, but this is not generally applicable, I don't think OP's problem is with `size` itself, it's probably just an example function.

Comment: Both good approaches... Thanks, dear colleagues!